# Using Splide Javascript Library in KotlinJS frontend

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop, kvision

I'm trying to find a kotlin based framework for a web-app and decided to try KVision as frontend framework (https://kvision.io).
I tried to use an external javascript library called Splide (https://splidejs.com) to get a slider, but I can't get it to run within my frontend.

My build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.targets.js.webpack.KotlinWebpackConfig

plugins {
    val kvisionVersion: String by System.getProperties()
    val kotlinVersion: String by System.getProperties()

    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("js")
    id("io.kvision") version kvisionVersion
}
val kvisionVersion: String by System.getProperties()
val webDir = file("src/main/web")
version = "0.0.1.alpha1"



dependencies {
    implementation(project(":json-dto"))
}


kotlin {
    js(IR) {
        browser {
            runTask {
                outputFileName = "kreatief.main.bundle.js"
                sourceMaps = false
                devServer = KotlinWebpackConfig.DevServer(
                    open = false,
                    port = 3000,
                    static = mutableListOf("$buildDir/processedResources/js/main")
                )
            }
            webpackTask {
                outputFileName = "kreatief.main.bundle.js"
            }
            testTask {
                useKarma {
                    useChromeHeadless()
                }
            }
        }
        binaries.executable()
    }
    sourceSets["main"].dependencies {
        implementation(npm("sass", "^1.29.0"))
        implementation(npm("sass-loader", "^10.1.0"))
        implementation(npm("@splidejs/splide", "4.0.0"))
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-bootstrap:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-i18n:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-rest:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-routing-navigo-ng:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-fontawesome:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-bootstrap-icons:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-toastify:$kvisionVersion")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
    }
    sourceSets["test"].dependencies {
        implementation(kotlin("test-js"))
        implementation("io.kvision:kvision-testutils:$kvisionVersion")
    }
    sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDir(webDir)
}
```

I defined a external class like this:

```
@JsModule("@splidejs/splide")
@JsNonModule
external class Splide(element: dynamic, options: dynamic) {
    fun mount(): Splide
}
```

And tried to use it like this:

```
 val splideElement = document.getElementById("mySplide")
 val options = json("perPage" to 3) // Specify Splide options here
 Splide(splideElement!!, options).mount()
```

When I call the code, I get this error:
Splide is not a constructor

I'm a bit lost here, as the Splide is called via the constructor call. There seems to be some javascript code behind it, but I don't know what exactly I have to call. I tried to find examples but they are often not really complex (like the kotlinJS example with is-sorted). I also looked up the questions with the kotlin-js-interop tag without finding a solution for my problem. It seems that I'm missing or misunderstood something.

I'm pretty sure my external class is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it. What is the correct way to use Splide (or any more complex external javascript library) in kotlinJS?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.